# Problems with 'adcli join' command: "invalid parameter supplied" and "unable to find a callback"

Tags: active-directory, sasl, sssd

I am seeing problems when using `adcli` to join a RHEL7 machine to a Windows domain:

```
couldn't connect to local.net domain: couldn't authenticate to active directory: SASL( -7): invalid parameter supplied: unable to find a callback: 32775
```

SSSD configuration is good (same as working box), Kerberos config is good (could `kinit`). I have even tried removing a working box from AD and re-adding it: that worked fine too.

Answer (score 2):

It turned out in this case to be a problem with the OpenLDAP configuration. In `/etc/openldap/ldap.conf` I had a line:

```
sasl_secprops minssf=0,maxssf=0
```

This line doesn't break machines that are already joined to the domain, but it does break the joining process!

I simply removed the line, but I expect (from my googling of the properties) that setting them to something other than 0 would work as well.

Comment: The line in `/etc/openldap/ldap.conf` is needed when you for example do ldapsearch and authenticate with kerberos credentials.

Comment: @JimmyHedman You can also use `-O maxssf=0`on the ldapsearch command line, so technically the line in `/etc/openldap/ldap.conf` is not needed.